# How to split monthly data smoothly into days?

Tags: python, bigdata, approximation

I have statistical reports, that are presented monthly. I would like to present the same data daily (keeping the total amount for the month). Of course, I can break the total values by the number of days in a month, but then a "step" is formed at the border of the months, which I want to avoid.

I have:

1. 01.01.2000 1000
2. 01.02.2000 800
3. 01.03.2000 1290

I need (daily data is approximate):

1. 01.01.2000 34.3
2. 02.01.2000 32.8
3. ...
4. 31.01.2000 28.2
5. 01.02.2000 28.4
6. 02.02.2000 28.7
7. .....
8. 29.02.2000 32.6
9. 01.03.2000 32.7
10. .....
11. 31.03.2000 45.1

How can I do this?

Comment: So, you want to split a months data into more or less random chunks? is that right? have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I want to split data not into random chunks but daily. I haven't done this before.

Comment: Well yes, but the daily data is to be generated somewhat randomly? Or do you have th data for each day? It is kinda unclear what you mean by "approximate".

Comment: Daily data should add up to monthly data, while having a certain smoothness (continuity of the first, second .... derivatives).
No random!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.